# What can I do in post-game in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

I have finished Borderlands a long time ago and all the side quests / missions. Is there anything I can do to have fun? Also I don't have any DLC and I don't look forward to getting one, I tried to look for quests which I didn't really find, also I did have a couple of side-quests that I completed after I finished, which were about 4 or 5.

I want to do something fun in the game so, if you can, give me advice.

Comment: You don't look forward to getting DLC? Do you mean that you have no intention of getting any, or that you simply don't care for the existing DLC? To the VTCer: while what's fun us indeed objecrtive, the titular question is objectively answerable.

Comment: No i mean like i  dont look forward to getting the dlc because i have heard not so good things about it and i cant afford getting them because i am getting bl2 in some time

Comment: If the answers helped you, please consider accepting one.

Answer (score 1):

If you already did everything available, you may want to start New Game+ mode, [Playthrough 2](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Playthrough_2):

> The character retains all items and levels gained in Playthrough 1 and will face off against similarly higher level enemies in an otherwise identical story. The enemy levels range from level 32 at the start, to level 50 by the end. Items will be encountered in higher level versions to match the enemies and general difficulty of Playthrough 2.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to playing the game in NG+ I’d also recommend replaying the game with a different character.

Each of the main characters encourages a dramatically different playstyle including stationary support, long range harassment, and tanky fist fighting.

Replaying the game with a new character allows you to flesh out situations and challenges you might not be accustomed to

Comment: Thanks but i already did that